# Can anyone explain the filter()-function to me?

Tags: python

Why is its output is *e e*?

Function that filters vowels

```
def fun(variable):
    letters = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    if (variable in letters):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Sequence

```
sequence = ['g', 'e', 'e', 'j', 'k', 's', 'p', 'r']
```

Using filter function

```
filtered = filter(fun, sequence)

print('The filtered letters are:')
for s in filtered:
    print(s)
```

Comment: @Yeshwin Please be nice, follow SO's CoC.

Comment: which line of the code are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Yup..seems confusing to me too...as you mentioned you are beginner, try to use few print statements to debug  your code

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. Simply saying that one doesn't understand multiple lines of code without specifying which part of the code is unclear is not focused enough. Also, the question doesn't show any research and without more focus probably isn't useful for others.

Answer (score 4):

in this example, `fun` will return `True` if your input variable `variable` is in the list `letters = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`. i.e. `fun('a')` will return `True` but `fun('b')` will return `False`.

[filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter) is a built in function which iterates through some sequence and calls some function for each item in the sequence, then returns the values for which the function returned a True value. In this case, is calls `fun('g')`, `fun('e')`, `fun('e')`, `fun('j')`, etc. and returns the values in `sequence` for which `fun` returns True.

Answer (score 2):

The function "fun" returns True if its argument is a vowel.  You see that, right?  If you add `print(fun('b'))` and `(print(fun(e'))` you can see that.

The `filter` function takes a sequence in its second parameter (which can be a string, a list, a tuple, or even a dict).  For each element in that sequence, one at a time, it calls the function in its first parameter.  If that function returns True, filter adds that element to the sequence it returns.  Thus, `filtered` ends up being a sequence of those members of `sequence` where `fun(x)` returned True.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand the filter function in python.

Please refer to this article:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter

The filter function will iterate every char in the sequence if the char exists in the letters and return all elements which are true.